# Rails application.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The old Rails used to have an application.rhtml file.  The newer version appear to have .html.erb files for each model. What's the reason there is currently no application.html.erb file?

Comment: And what did the old application.html.erb file show? One of your models? So why not make it a model.html.erb file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an `application.html.erb` file in the **app/view/layouts** directory if you want to have an application-wide layout file.